# React not importing global css; local comp ok

Tags: css, reactjs

React is not loading any global css. All local components are able to get its local styled-components. However, the global css is unable to generated to all components. 
I've tried different import paths and tried on different file, also `require(path)`. Not getting anything.

```
src
--modules
----component1
----component2
----asset
---------global.css
--index.js
```

global.css

```
.test-class{
    font-size: 100px;
    color:red;
}
```

at index.js

```
import './modules/assets/global.css'
render() {
return (<div className="test-class">Hello World</div>)}
```

HOWEVER if i use styledcomponents, it works.

Here's my webpack

```
module.exports = {
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/vendor.js', './src/index.js'],
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: isDev ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: isDev ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
    })
  ],
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts[x]?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'awesome-typescript-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader', // : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              path: '/postcss.config.js',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Do you get any build compilation error ?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I did not. When I inspect element, it's just completely blank on the class name.

Comment: can you share your project over github ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the classes from `global.css` but you are importing `app.css` in your `index.js` file. Import the correct file and you are set.

You are importing it correctly:

```
import './modules/assets/global.css';
```

Webpack looks good as well, but if you want to be sure just create a rule only for css since you don't seem to be using any scss or similar:

```
{test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader'},
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: false
        }
    },
```

Comment: sorry, that is a typo, i changed it to `global` to better understand here.

Comment: @jaimers did you try changing the css loader in webpack? also, try removing the MiniCssExtractPlugin, it makes things difficult for you to load afterwards, if you need to minify you can just pass the `minimize: true` to the options in the css-loader.

Comment: @jaimers is your path `assets` also a typo? It's also different in your directory structure and your imports.